# populate cck fields

Tags: nodes, entities

I have requirement, which deals with Order placing.
I am not using uber cart module or any other eCommerce related modules.
I have created a new content type names 'order placing', now the client requires that the title field should be filled by users name which I have added in user registration form. The second requirement is that the 'order placing' content type has a serial number field, which has to be auto generated depending on the database values.

Any ideas how could I achieve this?

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Auto Nodetitle](https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module along with the [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) module for your title requirement.  As for the second, you could hook into [hook_nodeapi()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) if Drupal 6, or [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) if Drupal 7, to populate your number field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion above, but for the second requirement I would need a hook function which I could use in template.php as the serial number has to be shown to the user. any ideas?

Comment: I am pretty certain you would have to do this in a custom module, not a theme.  But all this functionality is doing is populate the field programatically, so, whatever permissions you have on that field would be maintained.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try, custom module is what I wanted to avoid but guess I have no other choice.